# JavaCompiler Interface: Pass in variables at runtime

Tags: java, compiler-construction

I am using the interface that java provides to invoke the compilers from programs.

```
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();

StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null);

Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits = fileManager.getJavaFileObjectsFromStrings(Arrays.asList("MyClass.java"));

compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, null, null, null, compilationUnits).call();

fileManager.close();
```

Everything is working fine but what I want to be able to do is pass in variables to the project that i am compiling and compare the results to see if they are what is expected so i no the program is working properly. Kind of like how JUnit works to test classes. Is there methods in the JavaCompiler interface that allow you to pass in variables and read them then... something like `System.in()` and `System.out()`?

Comment: You mean you want to run the compiled program with test inputs?

Comment: Ya exactly, does JavaCompiler allow you to do this or will I have to do this another way?

Answer (score 0):

Running a (Java) program has not much to do with compiling it. Either you dynamically load the compiled classes and run them (e.g. in a new thread), or you use the `ProcessBuilder` to start a new VM, basically constructing a command line like "`java -cp /class/path my.compiled.MainClass ...`". The latter is probably preferred, since the program under test can't accidentally terminate your program through `System.exit()`.

Of course there's an *even better* solution: why don't you generate some JUnit tests programmatically (and invoke JUnit)?

Comment: by 'invoke JUnit' do you mean like calling upon the JUnitCore class and pass the classes into that or something similar?

Comment: Yes, `JUnitCore.runClasses(Class<?>...)` would be the easiest candidate. Assembling this class in memory could be tricky, the easiest solution will probably be to generate the JUnit-test on disk, and compile and run it.